# render fields individually drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm looking to render each field individually within page.tpl.php. My situation is, I have a image field, unlimited values, and a slideshow format. I want to take this field rendered with the slideshow formatting and place it where ever I want.

I've tried the following, but this doesn't apply the correct formatting, it just outputs with the default format:

```
$field_view_field_field_banners = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_banners');
$field_view_field_field_banners['#formatter'] = 'slideshow'; // I added this because the formatter was 'image'
echo render($field_view_field_field_banners);
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ok found I was missing something pretty basic after going through the code. It needs the display providing like so:

    $field_view_field_field_banners = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_banners', 'slideshow');
    echo render($field_view_field_field_banners);

One thing that is bugging me is though how can I find out the fields default display without having to manually put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth parameter that `field_view_field` takes can be the name of a view mode or it can be an array of the display setting keys: `label`, `type`, `settings`, and `weight`.

It looks as if you're trying to specify the field's format, but what's happening is that `field_view_field` is looking for a View Mode (like Default or Teaser) called "Slideshow."

Instead of

```
$foo = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_banners', 'slideshow');
```

Try:

```
$foo = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_banners', array('type' => 'slideshow'));
```

---

The answer to your second question is based on the one above really. The difference is between a view mode and a field formatter. It's highly likely that when you navigate to

```
/admin/structure/types/manage/foo/display
```

that you have two default view modes: `Default` and `Teaser`. If you've set the `field_banners` field to use `slideshow` formatter under the Default view mode, then there isn't any need to even use a fourth parameter since the "default" view mode will be used when none is specified.

In that scenario, you could just do:
    $foo = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_banners');

and `$foo` would have the `slideshow` format when rendered.

Check out the Drupal API doc for [field_view_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_field/7).